# c# Language : Error while trying to save parameters to MySql DB using C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using MySql database in my C# program.
Below is my code and when I execute the following method, it throws me an exception "MySql Syntax Exception".

Please help me in figuring out the error. Also let me know, if any further information is required to resolve this.

I would be very glad if you guys can help me.

```
    private void btnVerify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();

        try
        {
            string cmdText = "INSERT INTO cheque(customer_name, national_id, drawn_bank, chq_number, bnk_br_code, ac_number, drawndate, amount, commission_rate, commission, order, recieved_date, due_date, reminder_date, chq_image_frnt, chq_image_back) VALUES(@customer_name,@national_id,@drawn_bank,@chq_number,@bnk_br_code,@ac_number,@drawndate,@amount,@commission_rate,@commission,@order,@recieved_date,@due_date,@reminder_date,@chq_image_frnt,@chq_image_back)";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer_name", txtCustomerName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@national_id", txtIDNumber.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drawn_bank", txtDrawnBank.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@chq_number", txtChqNo.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bnk_br_code", txtBnkBrCode.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ac_number", TxtAcNo.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drawndate", dateTimePickerDrawnDate.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", TxtAmount.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@commission_rate", txtCommissionRate.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@commission", txtCommission.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@order", Ordercb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recieved_date", dateTimePickerRecieved.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@due_date", dateTimePickerDue.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reminder_date", dateTimePickerReminder.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@chq_image_frnt", picChqFrnt.Image);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@chq_image_back", picChqBack.Image);


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Cheque has been inserted to the database");
            ClearData();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (MySqlException x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Put some extra spaces like `INTO cheque (` and `VALUES (`

Comment: You have not stated how its failing.  Adding picChqFrnt.Image as a parameter is not going to insert the image, you will probably end up with its ToString.

Comment: The MySQL syntax error message goes on to say *...for the right syntax to use near `something`.*  That's the clue you need to sort out what's wrong.

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySql server version for the right syntax to use near 'order,recieved_date,due_date,reminder_date,chq_image_frnt,chq_image_back) V' at line 1" That's the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that's cause `order` is a reserve word in MySQL and needs to be escaped using backtique like

```
string cmdText = "INSERT INTO cheque(customer_name, national_id, drawn_bank, ..., `order`,...
```

That's what the error exactly saying *right syntax to use near '**order**,recieved_date,*

Do yourself a favor and stop using reserve word and key word as table or column name and save yourself from this issues in future

Comment: oh Thank you veru much. It works. I'll take your advice. :D